# Should どれ always be the first part of a sentence?

Tags: syntax

I have two sentences:

1. どれがあなたのペンですか？
2. あなたのペンはどれですか？

Are there any differences between the two sentences? I've heard that Japanese is a flexible language structure so I'm wondering if they are interchangeable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are 100% grammatical; That is for sure.

There is, however, a *slight* difference in nuance between the two.  It is so slight that I probably would not mention it if I were teaching a beginning or intermediate learner.

***Both mean "Which one is your pen?"***

The difference is in the main focus.

> 1) どれがあなたのペンですか？

focuses more on the "which one" part.

> 2) あなたのペンはどれですか？

focuses more on the "your" part -- in other words, the listener him/herself.